# Dart/Flutter json.decode and multiline value

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have json data with multiline. When I use `json.decode`, I've a error.

```
"FormatException (FormatException: Control character in string 
... "count": "1", "price": "5", "description": "It is a long established fact
```

My Json Data

```
var str = {
"description": "It is a long established fact 
that a reader will be distracted by the readable content 
of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English."
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: simply remove the quotes before the curly braces in the beginning and the end

Comment: Thank it's a error when I write in stackoverflow. I don't curly braces in the beginnin and the end of str. But the error exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want to encode or decode.

If you'd like to **encode** (create a JSON string out of data), you should make sure that the variable you supply to `json.encode` is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`. Also if you want to have multiline strings, you should use triple quotes `"""` for that in Dart. Here's an example

```
var data = {
"description": """It is a long established fact 
that a reader will be distracted by the readable content 
of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English."""
};

final jsonString = json.encode(data);
```

If you want to **decode** (turning a JSON string into a Dart object), your input string should be formatted properly. JSON doesn't have support strings so you'll need to add line breaks `\n`, these then have to be ignored in your string declaration as well, just like the quotes within your JSON, resulting in `\\n` and `\"`:

```
var str = "{\"description\": \"It is a long established fact\\nthat a reader will be distracted by the readable content\\nof a page when looking at its layout. The point\\nof using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.\"}";

final data = json.decode(str);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's OK. I use `data = str.toString().replaceAll('\n', '\\n');` for convert my string and `json.decode(data)` it's ok.